# Imgur image inaccessible

Tags: discussion, images

I noticed when this question, [How do these primes jump?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/264559/6094),
was bumped to the front page, the image [I posted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/264559/6094):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGsqP.jpg

will no longer load. Possibly my local problem?

Comment: I'm seeing it now.  Of course, I am in Brazil and may be looking at a Brazilian copy.  Gerhard "Looks Like The Original Though" Paseman, 2018.08.09.

Comment: I can see it...

Comment: There is a post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313779) From the answers it seems that at the moment the images work for some users and don't work for others.

Comment: Do you use ad-blocking extensions? This could be due to an overzealous Privacy Badger, for instance.

Comment: I now see it *is* a "local problem": I'm at a conference, and the university's unsecured guest wireless account disallows certain transactions that eduroam permits.

Comment: Joseph, there was a problem with the servers for a little while. It affected the entire network (people who use a custom profile picture (as opposed to Gravatar/Facebook/etc.) had their picture disappear for a short while). Any residual issues are due to caching, or as the old saying goes, [you should blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) In any case, this certainly not about connection security (unless you happened to be on a very oddly configured network exactly during the downtime, in which case it would have been both issues).